# Kegging: hose clamp technique?

Tags: kegging, co2

I'm re-attaching the CO2 to the home made kegerator I've inherited and I'm wondering if there are any steps one should follow for securing the hoses. Securing the hose clamps is pretty obvious, but I was wondering if there is anything I should do to preserve the plastic and or make for a better seal.

(Forgive my ignorance but if this was a part on a bike I'd use some grease for example - just wondering if there is an equivalent for gas tubing.)

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had mine set up for 15 years and I haven't done anything more than use the clamps.  Judging from that, that's enough.

Comment: I'll take 15 years of success as sufficient evidence! Thanks! I set it up and it is working fine. Pouring a one-off variant of a Spotted Cow clone - tastes great, perfectly carbonated.

Answer (score 1):

Some people swear by stepless Oetiker clamps. They have a 360 degree seal without bunching the tubing. It's a bit more expensive since they aren't reusable, but if you're having problems I would check them out.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was not having problems, just curious about what people do as I had never done it myself before. Turned out fine just using regular hose clamps.